# Push tag without push commit to remote repository with TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-tag

A console git client has a `git push origin <tag_name>` command for pushing a [tag](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) without commit to a remote repository.

What's the equivalent in TortoiseGit GUI?

Answer (score 36):

1. After Creating the Tag
2. Right click in the repo folder
3. From the context menu select "Git Sync..."
4. Change the "Push" drop down to "Push tags" (this will initiate the push)

[image: Git Sync window]

Comment: not good, because we want to specify the tag and not push all the trash tags

Comment: @PedroReis - I do not think that Tortoise has a command to push a single, I would just use command line for that. Out of curiosity, why do you create trash tags? I typically only make tags for important things that I would want to persist on the server. Locally I would use branches or stash save to mark code during development.

edit: looks like MrTux provided a solution to do this via the gui.

Answer (score 28):

*In order to push a specific tag* just enter the `<tag_name>` in the textbox for `Local` (it is also possible to select the tag on the RefBrowser after clicking on "▶")  and empty the `Remote` textbox within the `Ref` group.

[image]

This will result in `git push origin <tag_name>`.

*If you want to push all tags at once*, you can use the Sync dialog (select "Push tags" on the "Push" drop down) as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38838166/3906760.