# Create and push on tag

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

I modified my github repo code and now I want to create a tag and push project. I followed these steps:

- Commit
- Create tag
- Pull
- Push

But it did not work, the original project on master branch is cloned in the tag and the modified code remains only locally.

Comment: It is better to pull before committing to avoid eventually unneeded merges. Moreover, it could be helpful to show exactly the command you launched.

Comment: while pushing use `--tags` like `git push --tags origin master`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How push tag without push a commit to remote repository with TortoiseGit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958930/how-push-tag-without-push-a-commit-to-remote-repository-with-tortoisegit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the message you are getting?

The preferred method to push tags to a remote repository is the following.

```
$ git push <repo-name> <tag-name>
```

This command will push a single tag to the remote repository.

You can also use git `push --follow-tags`. It pushes both commits and tags that are both annotated and reachable from the pushed commits.