# How to push only a tag when remote repo has changes you dont want

Tags: git, tags, bitbucket, tortoisegit

I am using TortoiseGit on Windows 10 machine. I cloned a remote repo (a BitBucket one) to my local machine. Now in local repo I have created a tag which I want to push to remote repo. But remote repo now has some changes since I cloned it last time and I dont have those changes in my local repo and I dont want them in my local repo for now.

So I try to push my local tag to remote using TortoiseGit (Right-click on any white space to open right-click menu, then click on **TortoiseGit --> Push...** menu option, this open *Push* window, in *Push* window select the **Include Tags** option, then click **OK** button). But TortoiseGit rejected it and give an error

> [new tag] v3.2.0.1 -> v3.2.0.1 
>   ! [rejected] master -> master (fetch first) 
>   Updates were rejected because the remote contains
>   work that you do not have locally. This is usually caused by another
>   repository pushing to the same ref. You may want to first integrate
>   the remote changes (e.g., 'git pull...') before pushing again. See the
>   'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
>
> git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (8203 ms @ 2020-03-04 8:59:45
>   AM)

How can I solve this issue? I dont want to pull latest data from remote repo to my local repo, I just want to push my local tag to remote and nothing else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to only push a specific tag to remote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212452/how-to-only-push-a-specific-tag-to-remote)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+only+tag

Comment: @phd I was hoping to get answer of how to do it with TortoiseGit

Answer (score 1):

From the command line `git push origin v3.2.0.1`

Edit:
[Instruction in Tortoisegit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958930/how-push-tag-without-push-a-commit-to-remote-repository-with-Tortoisegit)

Comment: It works but preferable if you can tell how to do the same thing with TortoiseGit

Answer (score 1):

The tag `v3.2.0.1` was successfully pushed. `master` failed due to non-fast-forward.

On the Push window,

1. Leave all checkboxes unchecked. I guess you checked `Push all branches`. Don't check it.
2. Under `Ref`, fill in both `Local` and `Remote` editable drop-down lists with `refs/tags/v3.2.0.1`. For `Local`, you could also click the right arrow next to the drop-down list and select `RefBrowser` and then `tags` on the left and then double-click `v3.2.0.1` on the right. It might be okay to leave `Remote` blank when the repository is properly configured.
3. Press `OK`.

My TortoiseGit is v2.9.0.0.

Comment: In my case: Under _Ref_ section, the `Push all branches` option was unchecked and both the `Local` and `Remote` fields had **master** value. Under _Destination_ section, the `Remote` field had **origin** value. Under _Options_ section, the `Include Tags` and 'Autoload Putty Key' options were only checked.

Comment: @srh `Autoload Putty Key` should be checked if you are using SSH url. In your case, the settings are to push `master` and tags. When you want to push a specific tag only, replacing `master` with `refs/tags/<tagname>` would be okay.